# Execute bash commands in strict sequence on remote machine

Tags: linux, bash

I need to make sure that commands will be run strictly one after another on the remote machine. What are the best ways to achieve that? Any subsequent command has to wait till the previous is finished. Here's the `.sh` script i'm using, and thus far (though i'm not sure) it just seems like commands are being executed simultaneously.

```
ssh root@some_host << 'EOF'
   docker pull author/image:latest
   docker stop currently_running_container
   docker rm currently_runnning_container
   # etc
EOF
```

Comment: Unless you run them in the background with `&` at the end, commands are executed in sequence.

Comment: Maybe what you mean, is to stop script when any command fails? You can achieve that with `&&`. For example:

`docker pull author/image:latest && docker stop currently_running_container && docker rm currently_runnning_container`

Comment: @Barmar ok, got ya, if they are executed in sequence then that's rly what i need.
@RandallFlagg good point, thx for the tip! I shall probably add `&& \\` at the end of each line now, which would essentially be the same as before, except script would now stop if any command fails.